# Operation Problems in Java Generic

Tags: java, generics

I got some problem when i was learning Java Generic :

```
interface calculator<T, R> {
 public void execute(T t, R r);
}

class executeAdd<T, R> implements calculator<T, R> {
    private T first;
    private R second;

    public executeAdd(T first, R second) {
        super();
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(T t, R r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Object o = t + r //  ERROR ! What i could do it ?

    }  
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem???

Comment: You're trying to add two objects, you can't add objects

Comment: You can't do this.  You can't use the `+` operator on anything that's not primitives or `String`s.

Comment: @StefanBeike problem is shown in code comment

Comment: `Object o = t + r` what did you expect to happen
?

Comment: `new RandomObject() + new EvenMoreRandomObject()`

Comment: Classes and interfaces begin with uppercase, read the Java naming conventions.

Comment: This is expected. How can you expect object + object = object. This operation is only permitted on wrapper classes and string. But T and R could be any type of Objects.

Comment: You can only add java.lang.Number, java.lang.String and primitives but not java.lang.Objects...

Comment: I would suggest first to learn java basics and after start with generics. The question has nothing to do with them (or at least not too much). Please take a look at good Oracle's introduction to java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @LakatosGyula You cannot add objects using references of the abstract `java.lang.Number` class, but you can add together the concrete types that extend this class (`Double`, `Integer`, etc). Not sure whether you meant that, but just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @Teeg Thanks for the clarifying, I didn't knew about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object o = t + r
```

Objects cannot (under 99% of circumstances) be added together as such behaviour would be meaningless for the majority of objects. This is not specific to Generics.

Are you sure you want to use generics at all as you seem to be behaving towards T and R as if they are doubles (or annother numeric primative)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a numeric calculator, I think what you want is the following:

```
interface Calculator<T extends Number, R extends Number> {
    public void execute(T t, R r);
}

class ExecuteAdd<T extends Number, R extends Number> implements
        Calculator<T, R> {
    private final T first;
    private final R second;

    public ExecuteAdd(final T first, final R second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final T t, final R r) {
        // Check if integer, then add together as integer
        if (t instanceof Integer && r instanceof Integer) {
            final Integer result = t.intValue() + r.intValue();
        } else if (...) {
            // And so on with all subclasses of Number
        }
    }
}
```

This first declares the generics as subclasses of `Number` (which is parent class of all number classes in Java). This way you first make sure the objects passed can actually be added.

This is not a very elegant solution, and also it doesn't consider adding different `Number` subclasses together (e.g. integer with float).

Comment: I suppose you can also avoid the `if` statements by using `Number#doubleValue()` on both `Number` objects to give you a common type with which to perform the arithmetic, or something like that. Not sure if there are any down-sides to that though.

Comment: Hm, what about `BigInteger`? Also converting to `double` will make you lose integer values which cannot be represented exactly as floating-point values.

Comment: Yeah `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` would be one option; anything that provides methods for arithmetic operations. Converting to double could indeed cause you to lose an integer value (10 -> 9.999999....), this is true. I suppose you'd have to `round()` but that might not work 100% of the time either (and getting unnecessarily complicated).

Answer (score 0):

You could define `calculator` as

`interface calculator<T extends Number, R extends Number>`

That way you can use the `.xValue` methods for calculations.